# Select another column if the first one is empty

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I just find an example for this if the first column is NULL but i need to take another column if it's empty.

For example

```
SELECT artnr, arttxt, weightA if weight a is NULL or empty "" then weightB AS Weight
FROM artikel
```

Comment: Look up the case expression it is exactly what you need here.

Comment: @user2210516 check answer and do not forget to accept It as correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

You should use **[CASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)** expression.

```
SELECT artnr, arttxt, 
       CASE WHEN weightA is NULL OR weightA = '' THEN weightB ELSE weightA END AS Weight
FROM artikel
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT artnr, arttxt, 

CASE ISNULL(weightA, '') WHEN '' THEN weightB ELSE weightA END AS Weight

FROM artikel
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT artnr, arttxt, 
       COALESCE(NULLIF(weightA,''),weightB)as  [Weight]
FROM artikel

**just an dummy example to show how it handles NULL and '' spaces**

```
declare @t table (code varchar(10),food varchar(10))
insert into @t (code,food) values (NULL,'Sushi'),('','Rash')
select COALESCE(NULLIF(code,''),food) from @t
```

Comment: This is wrong, this will work only when weightA is null, but not when empty ''.

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT artnr, arttxt, COALESCE(NULLIF(weightA, ''), weightB) AS Weight
 FROM artikel
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution without the case statement

```
SELECT artnr
      ,arttxt
      ,COALESCE(NULLIF(weightA,''), weightB) 
FROM TableName
```